# Bootstrap scollspy not functioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, scrollspy

I'm running into an issue with scrollspy on Bootstrap v5.1. I am following along with the examples within the docs (listed below) however I can't get it to work; nothing seems to change upon scrolling.

When the user scrolls on the page, depending on which section they are viewing I want the corresponding link on the navbar to be active.

- **docs:** https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/scrollspy/
- **test site:** https://Test-Site.thatsliams.repl.co
- **site code:** https://replit.com/@ThatsLiamS/Test-Site

##### HTML Outline

```html
<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar">
    ...
    <nav id="navbar" class="menu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#about">About me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a></li>                
    </ul>
    </nav>
    ...
    <section id="about"> ... </section>
    <section id="skills"> ... </section>
    <section id="services"> ... </section>
    <section id="projects"> ... </section>

</body>
```

Comment: I guess you have to wrap those `sections` with the `div` that has `data-bs-spy="scroll"` currently you included the nav menu instead of the sections only,
Also please dont forget to included its javascript dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is actually working, its just that the `.active` class is added to the `.nav-link` anchor tag instead of the `.nav-item` list item.

Your CSS is targeting the `li.active` instead of `a.active`

```css
.sidebar .nav li a:hover, .sidebar .nav li.active a {
    color: #1d93e4;
    opacity: unset;
}
```

try this instead:

```css
.sidebar .nav li a:hover, .sidebar .nav li a.active  {
    color: #1d93e4;
    opacity: unset;
}
```

Here is the example of how to structure the nav (with the `.active` class in the `.nav-link`)

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navs-tabs/#base-nav

Or like this...

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
</nav>
```